# Sort data by fields from different collections using mongoose Node Js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two collections:

```
Person schema 
{
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
}


Story schema
{
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
}
```

I am using following query to get data from "`Story`" collection , but I want data should come sorted by "`name`" field of "`Person`" collection:

```
Story.find({"title" : "education"}).populate('fans').populate('_creator').exec()
```

How can I  sort data by "`name`" field of "`person`" collection?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
Story.find({"title" : "education"}).populate({path : 'fans', options :{sort : { name : 1 }}}).populate({path :'_creator' , options : {sort : { name : 1 }}}).exec();
```